# How to keep something (HUD) in front of camera all the time in Opengl

Tags: opengl, camera

Forgive me if I am asking similar question but I am not getting the right answer or may be I am unable to understand how to implement it 
I have to load HUD in front of camera I got camera DOF (x,y,z,apha, beta, gamma) I have only this information. How can I use camera DOF to translate the HUD in front of camera.

```
      float x =  eye[ 0 ].X()+ 0.465;
      float y =  eye[ 0 ].Y()+ 1.0; //bringing in front of camera
     float z =  eye[ 0 ].Z()- 0.08;
```

I am adding few magic numbers to x,z (above mentioned lines ) and then  HUD is right on the screen but if the camera is moved the hud is disappeared because these magic numbers are for only that camera position. I want to know the solution

one of my friend told me following

Feed the camera rotation into the HUD_DOF_All so the HUD rotates to face the camera square on.

Then in SetInstancePosition use the eyePos + eyeDir * M
I dont know how to achieve that or if it is true.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The HUD is 3d object that I loaded its not 2D orthographic object

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use camera DOF to translate the HUD in front of camera.

You're thinking too complicated: OpenGL just draws points, lines and triangles. OpenGL does not maintain a 3D scene!

To draw a HUD you simply draw it at the desired position. You do this simply be setting the right projection and modelview transformations that put the HUD at the desired location of the screen. If you're using the programmable pipeline (shaders) you set the appropriate uniforms. If you use the fixed function pipeline, setup a fresh, HUD appropriate projection and modelview matrix, then draw the HUD.